# How to properly detect use on a named/tagged Carrot on a stick?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to detect the use of a custom Carrot on a stick using scoreboards.

The way I'm doing this is by spawning one with a custom model, name and tag:

```
give @p carrot_on_a_stick{display:{Name:'"Rubick"'},CustomModelData:963,Rubick:1b}
```

Then I add a new scoreboard objective:

```
scoreboard objectives add rubiclick minecraft.used:minecraft.carrot_on_a_stick
```

Where I then use to detect if the player used the item but I use the detection to also make sure it has either the custom name, OR tag:

```
execute as @a[scores={rubiclick=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick"},tag:{display:{Name:'"Rubick"'}}}] at @s run effect give @a weakness 1 1 false
```

or

```
execute as @a[scores={rubiclick=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick"},tag:"Rubick:1b"}] at @s run effect give @a weakness 1 1 false
```

but neither method seems to work, yet I can detect a regular Carrot on a stick use with:

```
execute as @a[scores={rubiclick=1..},nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick"}}] at @s run effect give @a weakness 1 1 false
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you attempting to test for the name *or* the tag? I can't think of any scenarios where this type of testing is needed, just pick either the name or the tag, and test for that property only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first trial was the closest, but it was wrong:

---

You entered:

```
{
  SelectedItem: {
    id: "minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick"
  },
  tag: {
    display: {
      Name: '"Rubick"'
    }
  }
}
```

The correct NBT that you should enter is:

```
{
  SelectedItem: {
    id: "minecraft:carrot_on_a_stick",
    tag: {
      display: {
        Name: '"Rubick"'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice how `tag` is *inside* `SelectedItem`, not inside of it.

But while you're at it, you should avoid testing for custom item names. Instead, you should add a custom tag to your item. Your second failed trial above was an (incorrect) attempt to test for a custom item tag. This test failed because, you had the issue above, *and* your custom tag was in `""`s, signifying a string, when it isn't.

The correct format to test for a custom item tag is:

```
SelectedItem: {
  id: "_____",
  Count: 1b,
  tag: {
    Rubick: 1b
  }
}
```